# Unable to CSS rotate iframe containing embedded Youtube video in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, youtube, rotation

I want to show rotated embedded videos on my site. Im using iframes for displaying the videos. Rotating via css transform works well in all the browsers I've tested:

```
iframe{
    -moz-transform:    rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform:      rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(15deg);
    transform:         rotate(15deg);
}
```

However, for the specific combination of a youtube-video and IE browser (at least IE9), once the video loads, it is not rotated at all (although it is scaled to fit the rotated frame).

Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqYMX/

As is seen, other video sources like Vimeo is not a problem, even in IE. Thus, I'm guesing it has something to do with the contents of the youtube iframe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

*Edit: I have tested it in IE8 aswell, using a filter transform, with the same results as in IE9.*

Comment: Take note IE8 doesn't support the `(-ms-)transform` [**at all**](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Comment: You are right. However, the issue remains for IE9. I shouldnt have mentioned IE8 in the post, since I replace the specified css with filter transforms in this case.